# Add two ldap attributes with the same name

Tags: java, ldap

I would like to recreate the following ldiff using java:

```
DN: name=myName,ef=X2,ou=OuControls,o=Test,c=DE
objectClass: top
objectClass: myComponent
name: myName
```

The problem ist that I can't specify multiple objectClass Attributes.

If I examine the created node I only see the  objectClass: myComponent attribute.

My code looks like this:

```
 BasicAttribute oc1 = new BasicAttribute("objectClass","top");
 final DirContext context = LDAP_SERVICE.getContext();
 Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true); 
 attrs.put(oc1);
 BasicAttribute oc2 = new BasicAttribute("objectClass","myComponent");
 attrs.put(oc2);
 attrs.put("name", "myName");
 context.bind("name=myName,ef=X2,ou=OuControls,o=Test,c=DE", null, attrs);
```

The question is, how do I specify two attributes with the same name ?

Regards
  Roger

Comment: Did you try using `new BasicAttribute("objectClass",new String[] {"myComponent", "top"});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you (Works for me):

```
 Attribute attr = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
            attr.add("top");
            attr.add("myComponent");
```

-jim